# Replacing caret characters with sed

Tags: regex, sed, caret

I have lines in a file that look like this:

```
FA General,1234567^^^^^FA Student Letter- General^<<undefined>>^\\path\to\file.RTF
```

I'm trying to use sed to replace the caret characters with commas. If I use:

```
sed 's/\^/,/' file.txt
```

Nothing changes. I've also tried

```
sed 's/\\^/,/' file.txt
sed 's/^^/,/' file.txt
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to replace all carets?  I am sure if you look closely at your result you'll see that the first caret is replaced. So try this:

```
sed -e 's/\^/,/g' file.txt
```

Note the `g` to mean global replace, i.e, all matches.

Comment: You are correct. I can't believe I missed that; thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate this problem

```
set 'hello^world'
echo $1
sed 's/\^/,/' <<< "$1"
```

output

```
hello^world
hello,world
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try the `y` command:

```
sed 'y/^/,/'
```