# sed doesn't recognize special characters

Tags: unix, sed, turtle-rdf

I have a big ttl file and there are some errors when I load it

There are some special characters in the text that generates error :

```
<https://permid.org/1-5037622197>
        a                            tr-org:Organization ;
        mdaas:HeadquartersAddress    "Germany\n"^^xsd:string ;
        tr-common:hasPermId          "5037622197"^^xsd:string;
        tr-org:hasActivityStatus     tr-org:statusActive ;
        fibo-be-le-cb:isDomiciledIn  <http://sws.geonames.org/2921044/> ;
        vcard:organization-name      "ARWOBAU Immobilien und Beteiligungs GmbH"^^xsd:string .
```

I want to get ride off all ^^xsd:string. I used sed command but this seem to not work, please find the code below

```
sed -i -e 's/^^xsd:string//g' test.txt
```

test.txt is the example above

Comment: Escape the literal caret in the regex pattern. `sed -i 's/\^\^xsd:string//g' test.txt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing caret characters with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687044/replacing-caret-characters-with-sed)

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew I have tested your solution, it remove only "xsd:string" but the caret characters are still there

Comment: Are they `^` caret characters? What are you using to view the file? Maybe they are some unvisible characters? Check (and post if needed) the output of `cat -v` or `hexdump -C` of the relevant parts. Maybe just `sed -i 's/..xsd:string//g'`

Comment: Then, there are no caret *characters*  in your string.